# React redux geolocation with async and await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, react-redux

so I am trying to pull the lng and lat using geolocation with async and await. For some reason, it didn't wait for the promise to return before passes it to the reducer. I am getting another promise.

I expected to use await to get the result back from the promise before moving on to different parts of the program.

geolocation in reducer gets called before the result of the promise is returned.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: So you want to call getLocation that should get the position, and when it is successfully gotten you want to dispatch that position to redux store?

Comment: What you pass to the reducer looks strange. Usually the data part of the action is a value, array or object as this is assigned to the store's state but here you pass a function (receiveGeoLocation). I suggest you here dispatch Position object: {type: constants.LOCATION_RECEIVED, position: position }.

Comment: @croraf yes, but the problem is it gets dispatched to the store before the result comes back. The Promise comes back after any data returns. I can't get the await to work properly.

Comment: please avoid "pictures of code" - surely 30 lines of code is easy to copy/paste :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood the purpose of a `Promise`.

When you create a promise, it *does not* pause execution of the code.  In fact, the entire reason to use a promise is when you want the code to continue it's execution *without* waiting for a response.

There exist a number of middleware solutions to solving this problem.  [`ReduxThunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) is probably the most popular, but if you prefer a more async-await methodology you can also also tyr [`redux-asyncy-await`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-async-await).

A middleware solution such as these is required to handle async data calls.

Comment: thanks, dude. I fixed the problem now using reduxThunk.